# Delete all cells containing -1

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

I would like to start with data like Table A, below, and produce a new table like Table B, below, by deleting cells containing `-1`, and collapsing each column to eliminate empty cells.

I know how to do this manually, but I need to update Table A many times and evaluate table B every time, so I am looking for an automatic process. Is there any combination of functions that would allow this?

I have written the next macros. It should work by running it once. However, for some reason I need to run it several times to finally obtain Table B result. What is the reason for this?

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
  For j = 1 To 5
     If Cells(i, j).Value = -1 Then
         Cells(i, j).Select
         Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
     End If
  Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The site isn't really a "write me code" kind of place, but people will help you solve a problem you are trying to solve yourself.  You'll get a much better response if you describe what you've tried or researched and where you're stuck.  If you don't have a clue where to start, at least describe your thinking about how you might approach it to give people an idea of what level of information would be useful.

Comment: Remember automation need programming !. So my suggestion is, decide first what kind of solution you need VBA or Non-VBA. Other is, what is you idea to illustrate values which are not -1. Since D3, B4, A5 and many are in different rows but in Table B,  5 and 4s are in one row ? Don't make the question hypothetical, there must be a logic behind. As @fixer1234 also suggested you, explain the question in very proper way will help us to find good solution.

Comment: Change your code to `For i = 10 To 1 step -1`

Comment: Thank you Máté Juhász. That solves the last issue. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through cells downwards and deleting some of them with shifting others up cause that macro doesn't check all cells.

Easy solution here is to move upwards:

```
For i = 10 To 1 step -1
```